# JavaScript .Dialog Dynamic button names

Tags: javascript, button, dialog

So I have something similar to this

```
   $("#id").html(msg2show).dialog({
        //Other attributes
        buttons: {
           "Yes": function() {//Code},
           "No": function() {//Code}
         }
    });
```

I am adding other language support to my site. Is there a way to dynamically change "Yes" and "No" with out extra duplicate code?

I have tried using the following and replacing the strings above with variable names, however it seems to interpret the variable names as strings rather than the value of the variable.

```
var yes = 'Si';
var no = 'No';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build your buttons object before passing it to `.dialog()`, so you can use your variables as keys with bracket notation:

```
var yes = 'Si';
var no = 'No';
var buttons = {};
buttons[yes] = function() {};
buttons[no] = function() {};
$("#id").html(msg2show).dialog({
    //Other attributes
    buttons: buttons
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use the **text** attribute to set the names of the button. Look at this [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/chauhangs/t4vhp/2/)

```
   $( "#dialog" ).dialog({

   buttons: [
        {
         text: "OK",
         click: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
     }
   }
 ]
});
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know of that property, and that you could pass an array.